# Campagnolo drivetrain compatibility and noise

Tags: chain

My bike has 2009 Campagnolo Veloce 10 speed drivetrain. I recently changed the [cassette (still Veloce 10 speed)](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/campagnolo-veloce-10-speed-cassette/) and [chain (campagnolo Record 10 speed)](http://www.wiggle.com.au/campagnolo-record-10-speed-chain/). I assumed the fact that the chain was in the Record series wouldn't matter since it's still 10 speed.

However, I can't get the new setup to shift well. If I tune it so that it downshifts smoothly, it's noisy while pedaling (unless I exert a small force on the upshift lever). If I tune it so there's no noise while riding, it won't downshift properly.

Further reading of the Record chain says it's "Ultra narrow" so I'm wondering if that chain isn't compatible with the rest of the Veloce drivetrain.

Is my issue adjustment or compatibility?

Comment: I'd guess adjustment - the chains should be compatible (but I'm not a Campy expert).

Comment: Since you're in Melbourne, drop in to see Ray at [Mascot Cycles](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mascot+cycles). Don't say Andy sent you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up taking my bike to Dickie at Waverley Cycles. I had a couple of problems:

- The chain was too long (I hadn't removed enough links)
- The cable adjuster on the derailleur had stripped threads so had movement

He shortened the chain, screwed the adjuster further in and used the adjusters on the cable stops near the front of the bike to tune it and everything is now silky smooth

Comment: You can avoid mis-sizing a chain by just using an old chain which was properly sized as a reference and counting links (by laying them on the floor in parallel and matching them).

Comment: @Batman I would have done this but I was changing the cassette to a different size, so the chain length would need to be different as well.

Comment: Nice that you not only got it fixed, but learnt something for next time.